# What happens to a nuclear plant when you stop cooling it?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, climate-science

An IEA report says that many nuclear plants use freshwater for cooling, and that due to climate change, a growing portion of them are going to find themselves in high water stress areas. Does it mean we going to see a series of Chernobyls popping up all over the place in the nearest future, or are there some sort of safety nets that will shield nuclear power plants from the worst effects of climate change and water scarcity?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The question as stated is silly. Of course there are alternatives to continuing to operate a plant until the water supply runs dry, then risking a disaster because you have no plan for a safe shutdown despite decades of advance warning. The worst that could realistically happen is that the plants would have to be decommissioned early.

Comment: “You can’t give a reactor to much water”

Answer (score 4):

There's two questions here: one is what happens if you remove coolant from an operating plant, the other is whether there will be a "series of Chernobyls" in the future as a result.

The answer is that yes, for many types of reactor removing coolant while operating would cause a meltdown; however, some types of reactor, such as at least some molten salt reactors, are such that the coolant and fuel are together as one mixed material, so you literally can't "remove the coolant" without a very deliberate and intensive chemical separation process - hence why there's a lot of interest in this kind of reactor because it does not "fail deadly" by default.

(Smaller accidents with those are still possible, e.g. a leak resulting in molten radioactive sludge on the floor, but not Chernobyl-style ones with widespread atmospheric dispersal unless you, say, bombed the reactor to disintegrate it and disperse the material, at which point we're no longer really talking "accidents" but terrorism, and for those who worry about this, let me remind you there are already countless sites *right now* that *could* be the target of such attacks - esp. spent fuel pools and casks - but haven't been. Security and politics really is that good at preventing such.)

But the question of whether that would *actually* happen is almost certainly **no**: nobody sane would let the reactor run out of coolant because of climate changes and then overheat and melt. They would just shut the plant down much earlier as supplies start to become short. It's not like coolant would suddenly and unexpectedly vanish.

Answer (score 4):

Benrg's comment addresses the implied question. To the direct question:

> what happens when you stop cooling a reactor?

Specific mechanisms and long-term consequences depend on the reactor design, but can be broadly separated into two groups:

1: A fail-safe mechanism engages unless the operators disengage it, rendering the fuel inert and contained - at the expense of significant damage to the reactor itself. Chernobyl, Three Mile Island, and Fukushima are all cases of operators disabling fail-safe mechanisms that may have entirely prevented or significantly mitigated the disaster. If Godzilla comes along and vaporizes the river that cools the reactor, and the engineers do their jobs properly, the reactor stops working and some expensive parts have to be decommissioned and replaced.

2: The reactor fails safe and there's nothing that the operator can do about it.

Most extant reactors fall into the first category.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic time scale of control system actions in a reactor are of order ~seconds, while the characteristic time scales of variability of cooling water availability from natural sources is of order ~tens of years.

For this reason it is not difficult for the reactor control systems to automatically throttle back the power output of the reactor in response to changes in the availability of cooling water- simply by inserting the control or shim rods a little deeper into the reactor core year by year as the cooling water supply diminishes.